# How to remove ringing/anti-aliasing/gradients from PNG with ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am converting PNG icons to SVG, and results are better with sharp edges in the PNG. No gradients/anti-aliasing etc..

Results so far are ok, I am using a combination of `-kmeans`, `-median`, and `-morphology` arguments to ImageMagick to get the PNG into a nice state before vectorisation.

However, there are some pixels in the source image I am struggling to clean up, such as these slight gradients / antialiasing features of the image. I really need to despeckle/sharpen/remove any stray pixels as shown below.

[image: example of gradients]

Some ImageMagick options I've tried:

```
-kmeans 20 -median 5 -morphology CloseI Octagon:1
```

```
-statistic Mode 5 -median 7 -morphology Open Disk
```

[image: sample imagemagick output]

```
-kuwahara 3 -median 4  -morphology Open Disk
```

[image: sample imagemagick output]

```
-kmeans 20 -kuwahara 3 -median 4 -morphology open diamond:1 -unsharp 3
```

[image: sample imagemagick output]

The ideal output (zoomed into that potion of the image) would just be 3 colors, something along these lines:

[image: ideal output]

I'm struggling to find a combination of ImageMagick commands that don't result in messing up most of the image. I've tried googling for things like "ImageMagick despeckle" and "ImageMagick region flood fill" to try find a solution.

Here is a sample source image, and a sample output from ImageMagick:

Sample source image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcCco.png 
Sample output image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Duhl1.png

I have ImageMagick in my pipeline, but if there's a better tool or scripting language that produces better results in this area then I'm open to change.

Thanks for your ideas :)